VSCODE - No autocomplete for discord.js
I'm making a discord bot for a private server but it would be better if I could have VSCode autocompletion system for this.
I was expecting VSCode to make autocompletions for discord.js
I tried to use
const { Message } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
/**
  * 
  * @param {Message} messsage
  */
}

and
const { Message } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
/**
  * 
  * @param {Message} interaction
  */
}

but it didn't work

Is that JSDoc above a function?

JSDocs work along side function implementations, VSC will then provide intellisence. https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to make a slash commands with async execute(interaction) {}
but there isn't any autocompletion for interaction
It would be better with it

If you want to create a slash command, why not check the Discord documentation instead of the VSC autocompletion?
